# Generic conditional return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to infer the return result by testing the generic argument to the function.
I get errors on the `return` statement. However, when using the function return result is correctly inferred.

```
function arrayTest<T extends string | string[]>(
  data: T
): T extends string[] ? string[] : string | undefined {
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
    return data
  }
  else{
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? data : undefined
  }
}

const arr = arrayTest(['a']) // correctly infers array
const str = arrayTest('a') // infers string
```

```sh
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends string[] ? string[] : string | undefined'.
  Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends string[] ? string[] : string | undefined'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string[] ? string[] : string | undefined
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwCoFMDOUAPNorgB5S5gAm+ihqMYA5ogD4NROsDaAugD4AFAFgAUIkQ1kUZAC5E2CQEpFpClVr1GzFgMQB+Lj339Ei3aw6JwNXMGa4aiAN4SpMYMICC6LAB0MPh+GJjCMnIqKu6SUoiouFAgqEiRyB6IAL6ZuAA2+Lix8QlJKUgAsrIAFgEYtHAAtsIqiIKIAAwBAKxG0rLIFra0Dk40mTnikxIQCIQo6IgAvAtheITCvADkyFv8KjNzUCbLq1jrUMI7WypAA)

Comment: You're telling the compiler that if it's NOT an array, you want to return `data[0]`?

Comment: @Balastrong nice catch, thanks. I posted the wrong code. I've changed and simplified the example.

Comment: I don't think you can define what T extends twice.  That is exactly what it looks like the error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears that I've have needlessly complicated the whole thing, when it can all be done with function overloading as [Cuong-vu said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69213994/1489487)

```
function arrayTest(data: string): string | undefined
function arrayTest(data: string[]): string[]
function arrayTest(
  data: string | string[]
) {
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
    return data
  }
  else{
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? data : undefined
  }
}

const arr = arrayTest(['a']) // return string[]
const str = arrayTest('a') // return string | undefined
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwCoFMDOUAFACbJTIBcihqMYA5gJTW30OIA+i4Juw9XCQCwAKFCRYCFOix5CpclRpQ6jANoBdFirUMtYidHhI0GHAWJjEiMhVar2XXewOimiAN7XEMYEQBBWUwAOhh8IPNFCiYmb1EbG1RcKBBUJDtkHwBfH1wAG3xceMTEZNT0xABZcgALEIwwEjgAWyIPAD5EAAYQgFZEAH5bJURqXn5BEQTEXNE5sQgEQhlURABeVblLInUAcmQ97UXlqF0NrYsFA72mIA)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `TypeScript` has **[not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929)** inferring return types from input types yet. Meanwhile, you can use [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead

```
function arrayTest(
  data: string
): string 

function arrayTest(
  data: string[]
): string[]

function arrayTest<T>(
  data: T
): T | undefined {
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
    // return 1 // error here if try to return number when data is an array
    return data
  }
  else{
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? data : undefined
  }
}

const arr = arrayTest(['a'])
const str = arrayTest('a')
const num = arrayTest(1) // error here because of passing in number
```

But in your case, you can also use static return types, not as safe as function overload though

```
function arrayTest<T extends string | string[]>(
  data: T
): T | undefined {
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
    return data
  }
  else{
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? data : undefined
  }
}

const arr = arrayTest(['a'])
const str = arrayTest('a')
const num = arrayTest(1) // error
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the use case is, but you can make it even easier

```js
function arrayTest<T extends string | string[]>(
  data: T
): T {
   return data;
}

const arr = arrayTest(['a'])
const str = arrayTest('a')
```

If you define what `T` is, you can just say you're going to return `T` and it infers the right type.

Comment: I do have that `string | undefined` return result in the question. I've updated the code once again, to hopefully make a better example.